# NancyFX on Krestrel - Response Stream Closed

Tags: nancy, kestrel

I'm attempting it make a simple proxy server that will try to stream back data from an IP camera (the IP camera doesn't honor OPTIONS and has some other issues!).  I tried doing this using NancyFX and Krestrel with the following proxy module.  The idea was to just get 1028 bytes of data in and write it to the output stream asynchronously until canceled.

Here is a sample Nancy Module:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nancy;

namespace Server.Modules
{
    public class Proxy : NancyModule
    {
        public Proxy() : base("api/proxy")
        {
            Get("/", ProxyPage);
        }

        private async Task<Response> ProxyPage(dynamic args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Create HttpClient
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) // Make this global/cached and indexed by auth code
            {

                // Handle Authentication
                var auth = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers.Authorization) && Request.Headers.Authorization.Contains(" "))
                    auth = Request.Headers.Authorization.Split(' ')[1];
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Query.authorization))
                    auth = Request.Query.authorization;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", auth);

                // Create Proxy REsponse object
                var proxyResponse = new Response();

                // Get Async
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Request.Query["url"],
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);

                // Set Content Type
                proxyResponse.ContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();

                // Set Status Code
                proxyResponse.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)(int)response.StatusCode;

                // Handle stream writing
                proxyResponse.Contents = async s =>
                {
                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    var data = new byte[1028];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && (bytesRead = await result.Result.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
                    {
                        await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken);
                        await s.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
                    }
                    response.Dispose();
                };

                // Return Response container
                return proxyResponse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get through the while loop a couple times but then get an exception in FrameResponseStream (Krestrel): "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.'"   It appears that the stream is being closed (_state = FrameStreamState.Closed -- https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/Internal/Http/FrameResponseStream.cs) prematurely but I cannot figure out why or what I need to change to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

You should use ResponseContentRead instead of ResponseHeadersRead

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Request.Query["url"],
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken);
```